# Matlab: return complete solution of inverse cosine (acos)

Tags: matlab

I have some Matlab code of the following form:

`syms theta x 
 theta = acos(x)`

This returns a single solution for theta. However, I want to return the complete solution (between some limits).

For example,

x = cos(theta)

would give x=0.5 for theta = 60 degrees, 120 degrees, 420 degrees, etc. Therefore, in my code above, I want theta to return all these possible values.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have been searching google for hours but I can't find how to do this!

Many thanks!

Comment: All the possible values would mean - infinite number of solutions. Is it really what you want?

Comment: Does it really have to be symbolic math?

Comment: @EugeneSh. he stated "between some limits"

Comment: @excaza Right. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a numerical solution; like Benoit_11 I don't see the point of doing it symbolically in this context.

There are two solutions within the interval [-pi, pi], the larger one being returned by `acos`:

```
% solution within [0, pi]
theta1 = acos(x);
% solution within [-pi, 0]
theta2 = -acos(x);
```

These solutions repeat at steps of 2 pi. The number of possible steps downwards and upwards can be determined by the integer part of the distance between the basic solution and the respective limit (`lower` and `upper`), in units of 2 pi. For `theta1`:

```
% repetitions in 2 pi intervals within limits
sd = floor((theta1 - lower) / (2 * pi));
su = floor((upper - theta1) / (2 * pi));
theta1 = (-sd : su) * 2 * pi + theta1
```

And the same for `theta2`:

```
% repetitions in 2 pi intervals within limits
sd = floor((theta2 - lower) / (2 * pi));
su = floor((upper - theta2) / (2 * pi));
theta2 = (-sd : su) * 2 * pi + theta2
```

If you'd like one combined list of solutions, excluding possible duplicates:

```
theta = unique([theta1, theta2])
```

and in degrees:

```
theta = theta / pi * 180;
```

---

Example:

```
x = 0.5;
lower = -10;
upper = 30;
```

gives

```
theta =

   -7.3304   -5.2360   -1.0472    1.0472    5.2360    7.3304   11.5192   13.6136   17.8024   19.8968   24.0855   26.1799
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to use a loop:

```
for x = limit_inf:step:limit_sup
    theta(x) = acos(x);
end
```

And also define your limits and the step between them.